# symfony 3 get base url

Tags: php, yaml, symfony

I want to get top URL in service YAML like this :

```
app.meal_list_service:
    class: Acme\MealLogBundle\Service\MealListService
    arguments: ['@app.entity_repository_meal',getBaseUrl()"]
```

I cant find a good solution for this. I tried getting the URL from

`'%router.request_context.scheme%://%router.request_context.host%/'`

but this return only first part URL.

Comment: Example : %kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

My mistake. I thought you wanted the root project directory.
Try defining the project root path in your parameters.yml and pass it in a way similar to passing the %kernel.root_dir%.

```
// in parameters.yml
my_project_path: https://stackoverflow.com

// in your service.yml
app.meal_list_service:
    class: Acme\MealLogBundle\Service\MealListService
    arguments: 
        - '@app.entity_repository_meal'
        - '%my_project_path%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
app.meal_list_service:
    class: Acme\MealLogBundle\Service\MealListService
    arguments: ['@app.entity_repository_meal', '%request_stack%']
```

And in your service:

```
$baseUrl = $requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->getSchemeAndHttpHost();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can  always use __ DIR __ and create path from  it . Somtimes it's  faster  than DI and  passing  parameters to service.

Look  at  this , i'm using  it in trait to create path  for image  upload .
https://gist.github.com/poznet/9d9b0a8b707a527fa56d9bb1fa1979ad